Storage space with 2 new SSD disks failure after 2 months, how to recover the data back?
I am not sure what happened but after simple reboot the P: drive was not there.

At the beginning both disk where showing OK, but with the ERROR on the pool.
I did some tests and after that one start showing Warning.
I dont really mind just want to recover the data... I tried EASEUS software to do recover and it did recover but many files are on the FAILURE html report page ! this is damn, as I have some important data on it.
I am now trying ReclaiMe .. (EDIT: THIS WORKED AND RECOVERED ALL MY DATA)
Isn't there a simple way to recover the data ? what is the use of mirroring 2 disks ...
If I will replace the damaged disk, will I get the pool to work ?


Replacement disk:


You should be able to view the content is the mirror storage space with only one drive. However, it appears for whatever reason, you were using 2 drives to have nearly 2TB of storage space while you only had 1TB drives which means you would have needed at least 3 drives to suffer a drive failure without data loss. What size were these drives?

Those are 1TB drives. I am also sure none have any failure ... since they are brand new, I did not need 1.34TB of space I think I also fetched 900GB, since I did the two way mirror. where can I see the data beside disk recovery tools ?
Can I add anotehr disk and it will recover the drive ?

"where can I see the data beside disk recovery tools?" - If you are unable to view the contents of the drive with File Explorer then you will be limited to recovery tools. A healthy drive does not just drop off a storage pool

@Ramhound I tell you what bother me,  it was all working fine, I rebooted the PC and than the issues started.

@Sisi You have just discovered the desirability of having a backup of your data. Some people may say "duh! doesn't everyone know that?" because they've already heard it, but the actuality is that everyone needs to be informed of that. Also, you need to have more than one backup just in case one of them doesn't work just when you need it. If it's essential data, you will also want to have a copy stored somewhere that something bad like a house fire or city flood won't affect the backup.

@AndrewMorton I do have a backup of the data, I upload all .db files to dropbox via api every 3 hours. but it is not the latest data, and it would have take time to restore. just wondering why ssd failure after 3 months. btw on the same PC I also had a 2TB samsung 980 died also after 3 months, it was readable not writeable.

@Sisi How much data is being written to the drives? The specs for what I guess is your drive say the warranty is 1800 TBW.

@AndrewMorton how can I check that ? in smart ?

@Sisi Yes, but the drive manufacturer often supplies a utility that shows the data written, among other things, so if the S.M.A.R.T. data is difficult to interpret you could try that. Ah, here it is: Gigabyte SSD Toolbox

@AndrewMorton add

@Sisi What are the drives being used for? For example, are they being used to record the dryness of recently painted walls with a resolution of 60 seconds, or are they being used to log HTTP requests on a server that is being hammered by malware at gigabytes per second?

@Sisi If the Gigabyte utility is reporting power on hours as zero, you cannot rely on it:  it appears that the utility may not work with drives in a RAID/Storage Space. You should try to find some way of giving us useful data from the drives.

@AndrewMorton well it used for running a SAAS many process (like 200) are running but the db / logs are small I dont think disk usage is too high I will add a screenshot on the replacment disk I used for now.
